# Is the tag "<optional>" valid in dependencyManagement element?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, dependency-management

I am a bit confused about how the mechanism for [optional dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) works in Maven.
Is seems optional dependencies only work when specified directly, and not via Dependency Management.

---

I created three test projects p1-p3, with dependencies:

- p3 depends on p2
- p2 depends on p1

If I declare a dependency as optional in the **`<dependencies>`** element, this **works as expected**. POM of p2:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>testgroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>p1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <optional>true</optional>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Result**: The build of p3 pulls in p2, but *not* p1.

However, if I If I declare a dependency as optional in the **`<dependencyManagement>`** element, it **seems to be ignored**. POM of p2:

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>testgroup</groupId>
      <artifactId>p1</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>testgroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>p1</artifactId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Result**: The build of p3 pulls in p2 *and* p1.

---

Is this expected behavior? I could not find this documented anywhere.

Notes:

- Tested with Maven 3.0.3 and 3.2.1.
- To see whether the build of p3 used p1, I checked both the output of `mvn dependency:tree`, and the classpaths listed by `mvn -X` (with identical results).
- I also tried putting the `<dependencyManagement>` element into the POM of p1, instead of p2. The result was the same, i.e. `<optional>` had no effect.

Comment: Note to self: This looks like the same problem: [MNG-1630 - Optional tag in dependencyManagement is not inherited in the children projects](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-1630).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was reported as [MNG-1630](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-1630). Although closed as 'Fixed', [a comment suggests](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-1630?focusedCommentId=214598&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-214598):

> Actually, this issue was never fixed. The changes that have been committed in r354544 are insufficient as they neither update the DefaultArtifactCollector nor the DefaultModelDefaultsInjector to propage the optional flag from a managed dependency/artifact to a project dependency.

You've now opened a duplicate of this issue ([MNG-5632](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5632)) requesting either a behavioural or documentation change, which seems like an ideal way to track this.

Comment: [This is the bug report as of 2016](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5227) - fixed for maven version 3.4.

Comment: @Adam: ... and currently (re-)scheduled for inclusion in 3.6 - see the [Roadmap 2017](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Roadmap+2017).

Comment: The issue is still there in latest stable version (currently 3.9.2). The respective ticket [MNG-5227](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5227) is still open.